# i18n react how to make the url change when changing settings

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

i18n react how to make the url change when changing settings?

Eg, I am located at /community, the language is English. I switch the language to Russian - the url becomes /ru/community

Comment: Is the `url` being referred to the frontend or backend? You can possibly check the `namespaces` feature in the `i18next` framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71842594/3986110) on another thread. You can create a URL manipulator function or use [onLanguageChanged](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#onlanguagechanged) as in the APIs.